# Output contents of nested Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to write a Javascript function that takes an object and returns a prettified JSON-style string for debugging. I've tried iterating over each object property and logging the keys and values, but nested objects appear as `[object Object]`. How do I go about writing a short function to convert a nested object to a multiline string that I can print to the console?

I can't use the `JSON.stringify` function in my environment (iAd Producer) unfortunately. I'm looking for a simple function that I can copy-paste.

For example:

```
stringify({ data: { hello: 'world', with: { nested: 'objects' } } })
```

Should return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "hello": "world",
    "with": {
      "nested": "objects"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggestions to accompany downvotes would be much appreciated... This is a legitimate question from a colleague. Please take the time to improve the question by editing it or suggesting edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have JSON methods available, you could include a library to make them available:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Then you can do `JSON.stringify(myobj, null, 2)` for two space indented JSON as usual.

One of the big advantages of using a library, is that it has been thoroughly tested, and edge cases considered, and catered for.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is just for debugging, you could write a simple recursive function to stringify the contents of the object. Note that this will not work for Date objects and some others (printing instead `[object Date]`, etc.).

If you want to ensure all edge cases are covered and that you are producing valid production-grade JSON, use something like [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

```
function stringify(object, indentation) {
  if (typeof indentation === 'undefined') {
    indentation = 0;
  }

  var items = [];

  for (var key in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var value;

      switch (typeof object[key]) {
        case 'object':
          var type = Object.prototype.toString.call(object[key]);

          switch (type) {
            case '[object Null]':
              value = 'null';
              break;

            case '[object Array]':
            case '[object Object]':
              value = stringify(object[key], indentation + 2);
              break;

            default:
              value = type;
          }
          break;

        case 'string':
          value = '"' + object[key] + '"'
          break;

        default:
          value = object[key];
      }

      items.push(Array(indentation + 3).join(' ') + '"' + key + '": ' + value);
    }
  }

  return '{\n'
         + items.join(',\n') + '\n'
         + Array(indentation + 1).join(' ') + '}';
}
```

-

```
// Example:
console.log(stringify({ data: { hello: 'world', with: { nested: 'objects' } } }));
```

Comment: @dandavis: There's quite a lot this doesn't handle. Chris: Take dan's advice.

Comment: Agreed that json2 is the right bullet-proof solution. Have fixed for nulls and numbers, and added sensible output for dates - for use in debugging only.